# I would like to get all the players from all the games that one player is in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Games and players. I can get all the games with all the players. Or all the games belonging to a player. But what I want is all the games, with all the players that has a specify player in.

Tables

### Game

id
type
ect...

### Player

id
gameId => Game.id
playerName
userId => User.id

### User

id => Player.userId

my query that does not work is:

```
 Select g.id, g.type, .... 
     p.playerName, p.userId ....
     FROM game g
     LEFT JOIN player p on p.gameId = g.id
     WHERE p.userId in (42);
```

Comment: Can you sharpen up the details in this question a bit? What is `playerid`? What is `player.id`? What is `p.userid`? I'm also a little bit confused by the data structure because to me Player:Game is a many:many relationship but your tables dont really support that

Comment: Sorry, I notice that as you were asking. playerId should have been p.userId

Comment: Some sample data would go a long way to helping with this. Is Player the table that relates User and Game (breaks (Game:User many many relationship into Game:Player, Player:User 1:m m:1)?

Comment: Please share a full working example of your database such that others can reproduce your problem

Comment: I am away from the code, but will post exact tables this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that Player is a table that splits a M:M relationship between Game and User in to two 1:M relationships

```
 SELECT *
 FROM 
   game g
   INNER JOIN player p on p.gameId = g.id
   INNER JOIN user u on p.userid = u.id
 WHERE 
   p.gameID in (SELECT x.gameId FROM player x where x.userid = 42);
```

We need a subquery to get all the gameIDs that Player with userid 42 is a part of. Once we have the list of gameIDs we can get all those games together with *all* their players.

You can't get all the players out if you use the where clause to restrict the query to only user 42 as you had originally:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM 
   game g
   INNER JOIN player p on p.gameId = g.id
   INNER JOIN user u on p.userid = u.id
 WHERE 
   p.UserID = 42
```

This might well return a lot of rows, but they will only be for player 42.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN p... WHERE p IN/=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN p...`

Comment: True. I wasn't looking to fix that part of the breakdown in his logic...Not sure it deserves a downvote though!

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. It works like a charm.